# Application not listening on port 5000 on aws host

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, .net-core, amazon-elb

I developed a new application from scratch to upgrade a legacy application from 1.xx to 3.1. Microsoft changed Startup and launch code/api changed a lot since then.

The problem is that requests are not getting routed to my new application and I'm getting server at capacity error in postman API calls or 503 service unavailable.

I revert to old app and all requests work, something wrong with the startup configuration with this new project app.

**Legacy**

The legacy generated **Program.cs** looked like this and the listening port is hardcoded into the code. (*Works*)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

---

**New**

**Program.cs** looks like this. (Doesn't work)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<view.components.Startup>(); });
```

New l**aunchSettings.json** looks like this. (Note: My SSL port is 5000, that's where AWS Load Balancer is configured for).

Tried `https://*:5000;http://*:5001` as well as `https://127.0.0.1:5000;http://127.0.0.1:5001`

```
{
  
  "iisSettings": {
    
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
 
   "anonymousAuthentication": true, 

    "iisExpress": {
 
       "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:7193",
 
       "sslPort": 0

    }
  
  },
  
  "profiles": {

   "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
 
     "launchBrowser": true,
 
     "environmentVariables": {
 
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
 
     }

   },
 
   "Service": {
 
     "commandName": "Project",

     "launchBrowser": false,
 
     "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5000;http://localhost:5001",
 
     "environmentVariables": {
 
       "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
     }
 
   }
 
 }

}
```

---

My **LoadBalancer** in front of **EC2**.

[image]

Comment: So just so I follow, when you hard coded the port, using the same ALB everything worked and was routed correctly, after you updated the code is when the issue started? If that is the case make sure you are in prod on your env.

Comment: yes your statement is true, how do I ensure I'm in production, where do I set it?

Comment: right click on your main project file, go to properties and then debug you will see environments. Just to add make sure you always restart and rebuild when you change launchSettings.json

Comment: It's a .net core and I don't have visual studio on the server, if any settings it has to be in the code, and I'm running `dotnet run` command to run the instance, I've also copied `launchSettings.json` in my question for any edits there.

Comment: I also want to add that `env.IsDevelopment()` is returning false in my `Startup.cs`

Comment: I think it has to do something with integration with IIS -> `.UseIISIntegration()`, do I need to configure a site with IIS and the .net core application?

Comment: if you are using windows OS  than yes, but since its a dotnet core app you are not limited to windows. I dont know your OS, but if its anything but windows you dont need IIS, if windows you need to configure IIS in the app.

Comment: is there an article that you could reference to host this .net app on IIS. Apparently my legacy app worked fine since it had some programmatic constructs like `.UseIISIntegration()`.